# Post object inside array in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is my json format:

```
[
  { "testid":123 },
  { "testid":123 }
]
```

I am using submit method to post these data in object inside array. Below is the `component.ts` code:

```
 public submit() {

        this.loading = true
        var values = [];
        $('#example').find('td').each(function (j) {
            let param = { "testid": $('#et' + j).val(), }
            values.push(param);
        }); 
        this.array_fees = [];
        this.array_fees.push(values)
        console.log(this.array_fees[0]);
        this.contentservice.updatetestdetail(this.array_fees[0]).subscribe(data => {
            this.class = data;
        });
    }
```

After posting: The response am getting is :

```
[{testid: "1"}, {testid: "2"}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Can Someone please tell me from where empty object is coming when I m posting only 2 object..  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think error is in: $('#example').find('td').each(function(j)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on **submit()**,

```
public submit() {

        var values = [];
        $('#example').find('td').each((j) =>{
                let param = { "testid": j}
                values.push(param);
            }); 
        this.array_fees = [];
        this.array_fees = values;
        console.log(this.array_fees);

    }
```

and here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dm5ptn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.